# matplotlib + upgrade numpy causes python 2.7 to crash

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, pip

I run the following python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Then I run somewhere:

```
pip install --user --upgrade numpy
```

Hover over the pyplot figure, and python crashes immediatly (segmentation fault).

**Question:** Any idea how I can change the python code so python won't crash when I do the numpy command?

---

If you want the full story, I have written a distributed TensorFlow tester which installs tensorflow on multiple stations (which also causes numpy to be reinstalled). The tester also displays result graphs using matplotlib.

Comment: Are you trying to install numpy *while* the matplotlib script is running?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Well, yeah. I need to install Tensorflow in runtime, and Tensorflow installs numpy.

Comment: I can only tell you that I always had problems installing anything while python was executing. So I guess the idea would be to make sure this isn't happening; seen from the outside, one would just terminate all processes, install, then restart them again.